# Weird outline image with sculpting

Tags: image, sculpt

I'm new to blender and am trying sculpt mode. All its giving me, though, is an outline with a glitched out static backround inside. Is this a bug? [image: One image of it]

[image: Another image with the same picture as the first without any mapping]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I toggled the viewport shading and it was fixed. Not sure what it was, but that did the trick.

Comment: See [How to write good answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)